# JWT visible in chrome/firefox/ie resources tab

Tags: rest, jwt

im developing a app using a REST API, im using the well known JWT approach to secure my services but there is something bothering me and it is the fact that i can see my token in the resources tab in chrome (firefox, IE .. etc) i've set the token expiration time to 30mins and it just came to my mind that pretty much any developer can stole my backend url just by inspecting the javascript code and also stole my token from the said tab so he will have pretty much 30mins (with luck) to hack me up somehow .. is it (the localStorage) really the only place to store the token?

Comment: Well, the API should be designed and implemented with this threat in mind. A user (developer) can possibly create a better UI than you did and tokens will enable it. That's perfectly normal considering you wrote bulletproof API. I can right now talk to my internet banking API using tokens I see in the local storage - if banks are ok with this that's gotta mean something

Answer (score 1):

An attacker that has access to your machine would have access to localstorage just as easily as cookies.  Even Multi-Factor Authentication can't help you deal with someone getting control of your authenticated client (browser in this case).